# mongodb and or combo

Tags: mongodb

How do i do this in mongodb....

`(a || b || c) || (d && e)`

Answer (score 4):

(a || b || c) || (d && e) is equivalent to (a || b || c || (d && e))

if abcde are your fields and 12345 are the values (simple case you can put whatever as those expressions):

```
 db.foo.find( { $or : [ { a : 1 } , { b : 2 },{ c : 3 },{ d : 4 , e :5} ] } );
```

Note this is for mongodb >= 1.5.3 earlier ones do not have $or