# "and" within "or" in PHP's MongoDB query

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

[mongodb and or combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884942/mongodb-and-or-combo) Similar to this except I'm using php and getting [MongoCursorException] $or array must contain objects.

Also read this http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or

**How can one nest an "AND" inside of an "OR" in MongoDB via PHP?**  Here is my conditions argument (via var_export):

```
'group_id' => '4eec13b5-aeb4-48ee-9619-449125af0e18',
'$or' => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'active' => 0,
      'user_id' => '4eea7b76-5d34-4036-8344-120c0aaa1bdc',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'active' => 1,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Need list of posts that are in a group id AND are active OR (belong to the user AND are not active).

Extremely easy in SQL but whichever variation I try in the MongoDB via PHP query I get the $or error.  Is this possible?  Is an $and required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your query is just incorrect. In JSON, it would look like

```
{ 
   "group_id" : "4eec13b5-aeb4-48ee-9619-449125af0e18",
   "$or" : [ 
                    [ { "active" : 0, "user_id" : "4eea7b76-5d34-4036-8344-120c0aaa1bdc" } ],
                    [ null, { "active" : 1 } ] 
           ]
}
```

for  group id AND are active OR (belong to the user AND are not active), it should be represented somewhat as :

```
{ 
   "group_id" : "4eec13b5-aeb4-48ee-9619-449125af0e18",
   "$or" : [ 
                    { "active" : 0, "user_id" : "4eea7b76-5d34-4036-8344-120c0aaa1bdc" },
                    { "active" : 1 } 
           ]
}
```

More or less, it will look like this in PHP

```
array(
'group_id' => '4eec13b5-aeb4-48ee-9619-449125af0e18',
'$or' => 
     array (
        0 => 
           array (
               'active' => 0,
               'user_id' => '4eea7b76-5d34-4036-8344-120c0aaa1bdc',
           ),
        1 => 
           array (
               'active' => 1,
           )
     ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't solve the problem until I started viewing my php as json.  Testing queries at the command line with json is a very good way to figure things out with mongo!